# Unable to use the reduceRegion function of google earth engine in python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I try to convert a javascript google earth engine workflow into python and I face some strange errors. More specifically, I use the below script in order to calculate the mean elevation of a predefined area:

```
feature_geometry = {
    'type': 'MultiPolygon',
    'coordinates': [[[
        [-113.11777746091163,35.924059850042575],
        [-112.43662511716161,35.924059850042575],
        [-112.43662511716161, 36.52671462113273],
        [-113.11777746091163, 36.52671462113273],
        [-113.11777746091163,35.924059850042575]
    ]]]
}

#Compute the mean elevation in the polygon.
meanDict = srtm.reduceRegion(
  reducer= ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry= feature_geometry,
  scale= 90
)


mean = meanDict.get('elevation');
print(mean)
```

When I execute the above, I get back a dictionary like the one below:

```
ee.ComputedObject({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "dictionary": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
        "image": {
          "type": "Invocation",
          "arguments": {
            "id": "CGIAR/SRTM90_V4"
          },
          "functionName": "Image.load"
        },
        "reducer": {
          "type": "Invocation",
          "arguments": {},
          "functionName": "Reducer.mean"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                [
                  -113.11777746091163,
                  35.924059850042575
                ],
                [
                  -112.43662511716161,
                  35.924059850042575
                ],
                [
                  -112.43662511716161,
                  36.52671462113273
                ],
                [
                  -113.11777746091163,
                  36.52671462113273
                ],
                [
                  -113.11777746091163,
                  35.924059850042575
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        },
        "scale": 90
      },
      "functionName": "Image.reduceRegion"
    },
    "key": "elevation"
  },
  "functionName": "Dictionary.get"
})
```

Instead the javascript code [from this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_03) returns a string value with the result.

What is the correct way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the python earth engine API, `print` does not execute the server side code and return the value like it does in javascript. From https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/deferred_execution (an aside near the bottom):

> (In Python, it's necessary to call getInfo() on the object being printed; otherwise the request JSON is printed).

So to get the value, you need to explicitly call `.getInfo()`, like this:

```
mean = meanDict.get('elevation').getInfo();
print(mean)
```

To get a better grasp of what's happening I would recommmend studying the link above and also [this page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server). In my experience, client vs. server side stuff in EE is the most difficult thing to keep tabs on.